# How to prove $\mathbb{R}^{2} \rtimes_{\phi_{n}} SO(2) \not \cong \mathbb{R}^{2} \rtimes_{\phi_{m}} SO(2)$ for different $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product

Let $$\begin{align*}
r_{\theta} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta  & -\sin \theta \\  \sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}$$ for $\theta \in[0,2\pi]$ . Then all $r_{\theta}$ forms $SO(2)$ .

Let $$\begin{align*}
\phi_{n}:& SO(2) \to \text{Aut}(\mathbb{R}^{2}) 
\\ &r_{\theta} \to r_{n\theta}
\end{align*}$$ be a homomorphism, and use it to construct semi-direct product $\mathbb{R}^{2} \rtimes_{\phi_{n}} SO(2)$.

Thus the operation in $\mathbb{R}^{2} \rtimes_{\phi_{n}} SO(2)$ will be $$\begin{align*}
(v, r_{\theta}) (u ,r_{\theta'}) &=  (v+ r_{\theta}^{n}(u),r_{\theta + \theta '}) 
\\ &=   (v+ r_{n\theta}^{}(u),r_{\theta + \theta '})
\end{align*}$$
I want to show that for different $n ,m \in \mathbb{N}$ , we have $$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R}^{2} \rtimes_{\phi_{n}} SO(2) \not \cong \mathbb{R}^{2} \rtimes_{\phi_{m}} SO(2)
\end{align*}$$
I tried to show this by contradiction. Suppose there exists an isomorphism $\psi$, then it should preserve the order of the elements. I want to use this fact to construct a contradiction, but I got stuck for a quite long time. Any help on this? Thanks!

Comment: I think the crux of this is going to be in the second term of the first argument.

Comment: @Chris Do you mind providing more details or the solution?

Comment: I haven’t attempted anything, but that term is the only one which involves $n$ and $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Define

### $$\color{purple}{G(n)}:= \mathbb{R}^2\rtimes_{\varphi_n}SO(2)$$

with product defined relative to $\varphi_n$ as above. Consider integer powers of an element in $G(n)$:
$\color{purple}{(u,r_{\theta})}$

$(u,r_{\theta})^2 = (u,r_{\theta})(u,r_{\theta}) = (u+r_{n\theta}(u),r_{2\theta})$

$(u,r_{\theta})^3 = (u,r_{\theta})(u,r_{\theta})^2 = (u,r_{\theta})(u+r_{n\theta}(u),r_{2\theta}) = \big(u+r_{n\theta}(u+r_{n\theta}(u)),r_{3\theta}\big)$

$\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }= (u+r_{n\theta}(u)+r_{n\theta}(r_{n\theta}(u)),r_{3\theta}) = (u+r_{n\theta}(u)+r_{2n\theta}(u),r_{3\theta})$
$\vdots$
$\color{blue}{(u,r_{\theta})^x = \bigg(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{x-1} r_{kn\theta}(u),r_{x\theta}\bigg)},$
where Linearity of the $r_{}$'s has been applied, as well as the special fact $r_{\alpha}r_{\beta} = r_{\alpha+\beta}$.

---

If $x$ is the *order* of $(u,r_{\theta})$, then:
$$(u,r_{\theta})^x = \color{purple}{1_{G(n)}} = (0,r_0)$$
$$\implies \sum\limits_{k=0}^{x-1} r_{kn\theta}(u) = 0\text{ }(\in\mathbb{R}^2)\text{ }\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }\text{ }r_{x\theta} = r_0\text{ }(\in SO(2)).$$
The latter of which gives:
$$\theta = \frac{2\pi}{x}\color{purple}{l},\text{ for }l\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
Substituting this into the prior gives the *master equation* that a finitely ordered element of $G(n)$ satisfies:

### $$\color{darkblue}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{x-1}(r_{\frac{2\pi k}{x}})^{(nl)}(u) = 0}$$

---

Suppose now, that $\color{purple}{\Phi:G(n)\to G(m)}$ is an *isomorphism* and that $\color{purple}{(v,r_{\phi})} := \Phi((u,r_{\theta}))$. Since $\color{red}{\text{isomorphisms preserve order}}$, we have corresponding information for $(v,r_{\phi})$. That is:
$$\phi = \frac{2\pi}{x}\color{purple}{l'},\text{ for }l'\in \mathbb{Z}\text{ and }$$

### $$\color{darkblue}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{x-1}(r_{\frac{2\pi k}{x}})^{(ml')}(v) = 0}.$$

---

Equating across the zero vector and combining the sums gives:
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{x-1}\bigg[\big(r_{\frac{2\pi k}{x}}\big)^{(ml')}(v) - \big(r_{\frac{2\pi k}{x}}\big)^{(nl)}(u)\bigg] = 0$$
$$\implies \sum\limits_{k=0}^{x-1}\big(r_{\frac{2\pi k}{x}}\big)^{(ml')}\bigg[(v) - \big(r_{\frac{2\pi k}{x}}\big)^{(-ml')}\big(r_{\frac{2\pi k}{x}}\big)^{(nl)}(u)\bigg] = 0.$$
Since we know $0\notin SO(2)$, it must be the case that:
$$\forall k\in \{0,...,x-1\}:\text{ }v = (r_{\frac{2\pi}{x}})^{(nl-ml')}(u).$$
Clearly $v$ can't be several different images of $u$ at once, so it must be the case that:
$$nl = ml'.$$
But this important result gives:

$$v = u\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }\phi = \frac{n}{m}\theta.$$
In other words, elements of finite order have designated (isomorphic) images of the form:

### $$\color{darkorange}{\Phi\big((u,r_{\theta})\big) = \big(u,r_{(n/m)\theta}\big).}$$

---

Now, we may show $$\exists g\neq 1_{G(n)}\in ker(\Phi:G(n)\to G(m)),$$
which contradicts *injectivity* unless $m=n$. [Exercise] $\blacksquare$

Comment: I was able to deduce an explicit form for the images of a subset of finitely ordered elements of $G(n)$. From this, we can show the kernel is non-trivial.

Comment: Switched it to iso, same argument